# UWP: Add InlineUIContainer to Hyperlink fails

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

In my UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app I need to create a `Hyperlink` element with an image in it:

```
var hyperlink = new Hyperlink();
var container = new InlineUIContainer { Child = new Image() { ... } }; 
hyperlink.Inlines.Add(container);
```

This `Hyperlink` gets later added to a `TextBlock` together with other elements. My problem is, that the last line (`Inlines.Add()`) throws an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Does someone know a way around this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do this. A workaround is to use a `RichTextBlock` with a `HyperlinkButton` instead.

So try doing this structure in code -

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Italic>This is an inline image.</Italic>

        <InlineUIContainer>
            <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://www.nba.com">
                <Image Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" />
            </HyperlinkButton>
        </InlineUIContainer>

        Yes it is.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```